# SQL - Convert Columns of Each Row to New Table Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I can't seem to find a more direct solution to this. I'm trying to take a table with multiple fields and "pivot" that info to a table with a more flexible format for the data.

I have the following summarized table:

```
Item | Info1 | Info2 | Date1 | Date2
-------------------------------------
item1  info11  info12  date11  date12
item2  info21  info22  date21  date22
```

Pretty much I want this table to be a "many" table instead of "one", and want the following:

```
Item | Info | Date 
--------------------
item1  info11 date11
item1  info12 date12
item2  info21 date21
item2  info22 date22
```

The table I'm working with has way more fields, but this is basically the concept I'm struggling with in SQL code. I can imagine running a while loop to perform the data pivot for each record, or maybe there is something easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually isn't a `PIVOT`.  The `PIVOT` function converts rows into columns, you want to `UNPIVOT`which converts multiple columns into rows.

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot the pairs of columns:

```
select 
  c.item,
  c.info,
  c.date
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select item, info1, date1 union all
  select item, info2, date2
) c (item, info, date);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e399/1)

This could also be done using a UNION ALL query:

```
select item, info1, date1
from yourtable
union all
select item, info2, date2
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e399/2)

Comment: wow that is awesomely a lot simpler than what I had been reading. Thank you! This will work like a charm.